# Will memory mapped file be faster than BufferedStream?

Tags: java, file-io

Anyone has experience of performance comparison between memory mapped file and bufferedStream? Will memory mapped file be faster than BufferStream?

Comment: Why don't you do a comparison of your own, that makes the most sense

Answer (score 2):

Using a BufferedInput/Output will be faster and simpler for you, and often this matters more. ;)

You can get much the same throughput as the bottle neck is usually your underlying disk or storage.  Even if you have a fast SSD you can get close to the maximum throughput with both ways of accessing data.

For latency of updates memory mapped files can be 10 - 100x faster.  However, you rarely need this unless you also have a process attempting to read the file at a the same time.

Comment: It is also worth noting that memory mapping a large file increases your application's memory footprint, which can have a negative impact on overall system performance.  (In extreme cases, very negative ...)

Comment: In a 32-bit program it can cause you to run out of virtual memory which can crash the JVM.  However in a 64-bit JVM I have created 8 TB memory mapped files, mapped into Java without a problem. ;) http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html

Comment: That may be true, but if you have substantially less physical memory than your mapped file, and you access the mapped file fast enough in a random pattern, then I can **guarantee** that you will end up with severe disk/vm thrashing.  Even making multiple sequential passes through a huge mapped file can make life unpleasant for other applications.

Comment: @Stephen C, This is all true.  However if you need to maintain or access this much data, memory mapped files will be the best option. c.f. if you try to use more heap than main memory, your JVM, if not your machine will be impossible to use. However, with a memory mapped file(s) it depends on your access pattern as to impact on the system. Its worth noting that they have almost no impact on your full GC times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Do you need any particular setting for JVM to map large file? I've got `OutOfMemoryError` for 512Mb file on x32 platform with `-Xmx1300m` (but I am not sure that heap size mappers).

Comment: In 32-bit windows, an application can only have about 1.5 GB of virtual memory in total. To map in 0.5 GB, you need to reduce your maximum heap size. Try `-mx512m` instead.  With a 64-bit JVM on 64-bit windows, the maximum size is virtually unlimited if you will pardon the pun.